# Initializing an instance variable

Tags: instance, constructor

What are the benefits of initializing an instance variable in an instance block rather than constructor of the class?

Comment: The past couple of questions you've asked have been about some pretty basic things. I'd recommend going through some trails/modules over at https://trailhead.salesforce.com to get a handle on the basics. Trailhead is likely to be a better resource than this site is when it comes to starting out with Salesforce (or even if you're just new to a particular concept/feature). The [Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dev_guide.htm) is also a good thing to reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you instantiate the variables inside constructors so you can ensure "contract" is followed when using your class. Calling class will be forced to provide the values the moment they construct and not lines after which they may forget and therefore change the behavior of your class.

Do not use them for their "benefits" because these can be both used and are based on "design" and your requirement and not trade-offs/pros-cons, etc

```
public MyClass {

    public String instanceVar;   // can be called directly outside the class
    private String privateVar;   // can only be populated inside constructor

    public MyClass {
    }

    public MyClass(String privateVar) {
        this.privateVar = privateVar; // replace the privateVar with the new values
    }
}
```

calling class:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
mc.instanceVar = 'any value';

MyClass mc = new MyClass('must have value upon instantiation'); // this will go to privateVar
```